# Send data to another C++ program

Tags: c++, inter-process-communicat

Is it possible to send data to another C++ program, ***without being able to modify the other program*** (since a few people seem to be missing this important restriction)? If so, how would you do it? My current method involves creating a temporary file and starting the other program with the filename as a parameter. The only problem is that this leaves a bunch of temporary files laying around to clean up later, which is not wanted.

Edit: Also, boost is ***not*** an option.

Comment: Can the other program use stdin as its input file? If so, you could probably just pipe it.

Comment: Did you read about the various [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanisms available on your system?

Comment: @FredLarson I don't think so. I believe it *only* takes a filename as a startup parameter.

Comment: What operating system are you writing for?

Comment: @Robᵩ Preferably cross platform, but Linux to start with.

Comment: @Drise: Some programs will use stdin if no filename is specified, or will take "-" as a filename to mean stdin.

Comment: @FredLarson Unfortunately, it seems this one does not. I tried both methods: The first resulted it it specifying that I needed a filename, and the second stated it was an invalid file.

Comment: Interprocess communication is a common topic.
link about how to do it in windows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx
and about how to do it in linux http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html

Comment: It all depends! what kind of input does the other program read?

Comment: @ahenderson This has been established. It reads a filename passed as a parameter on start up. No other input is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, building a pipe to stdin is the way to go, if the 2nd program supports it. As Fred mentioned in a comment, many programs read stdin if either there is no named file provided, or if `-` is used as the filename.

If it **must** take a filename, and you are using Linux, then try this: create a pipe, and pass `/dev/fd/<fd-number>` or `/proc/self/fd/<fd-number>` on the command line.

By way of example, here is hello-world 2.0:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main () {

  int pfd[2];
  int rc;

  if( pipe(pfd) < 0 ) {
    perror("pipe");
    return 1;
  }

  switch(fork()) {
  case -1: // Error
    perror("fork");
    return 1;

  case 0: { // Child
    // Close the writing end of the pipe
    close(pfd[1]);

    // Create a filename that refers to reading end of pipe
    std::ostringstream path;
    path << "/proc/self/fd/" << pfd[0];

    // Invoke the subject program. "cat" will do nicely.
    execlp("/bin/cat", "cat", path.str().c_str(), (char*)0);

    // If we got here, then something went wrong, then execlp failed
    perror("exec");
    return 1;
  }

  default: // Parent
    // Close the reading end.
    close(pfd[0]);

    // Write to the pipe. Since "cat" is on the other end, expect to
    // see "Hello, world" on your screen.
    if (write(pfd[1], "Hello, world\n", 13) != 13)
      perror("write");

    // Signal "cat" that we are done writing
    close(pfd[1]);

    // Wait for "cat" to finish its business
    if( wait(0) < 0)
      perror("wait");

    // Everything's okay
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the latter?

Answer (score 1):

You could use sockets.  It sounds like both application are on the same host, so you just identify the peers as localhost:portA and localhost:port B.  And if you do it this way you can eventually graduate to do network IO.  No temp files, no mystery parse errors or file deletions.  TCP guarantees packet delivery and guarantees they will be ordered correctly.

So yeah, I would consider creating an synchronous socket server (use asynchronous if you anticipate having tons of peers).  One benefit over pipe oriented IPC is that TCP sockets are completely universal.  Piping varies dramatically based upon what system you are on (consider Windows named pipes vs implicit and explicit POSIX pipes -> very different).

Comment: Why do I get the feeling this requires modification of the secondary program?

Comment: It does.  I assume you have control over both pieces of source, no?

Comment: *without being able to modify the other program* No, I don't.

Comment: It sounds like the thing that is bothering you is just there being a bunch of temp files left over.  This problem is easily solved with a 3 or 4 line shell script and nothing else. Line 0: #!/bin/bash.  Line 1: T=\`mktemp temp.XXXXX.file\`.  Line 2: ./secondProgram -p "$T".  Line 3: rm -f "$T" .  This script does exactly what you want and leaves no temp files remaining afterwards.  No extra coding required.

Comment: Or, Line 1a: `trap "rm -f $T" 0` instead of line 3.

Comment: @Robᵩ Touche.  But you get the idea.